# OpAmp choice and circuit configuration for DAC amplification to speaker

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio

For a school project we're using a uC with a DAC which outputs values between 0V-3.3V, which we want to amplify and feed into a speaker.

We haven't settled for a particular speaker but considering it would be mounted on a PCB it should be assumed to be a small 8~16Ohm one.

Now the DAC needs a minimum load of 1kOhm and it obviously can't be fed directly to the speaker so we were juggling a few options.

The first one was to use the widely available LM386 in the following configuration:

[image: Circuit configuration and voltage diagram]

Blue signal is the DAC's output, green signal is the LM386's output, red signal is what reaches the speaker after the filter.

This seemed to be the easiest way but, it has a huge problem in that the DAC's output has to be limited to +-0.06V in the example, which cuts down the DAC's resolution and we assume introduces a lot of noise. Even with such a tiny signal the LM386 seems to be saturated on the top too, as it's cutting off the signal's peaks.

A second idea was to use an LM4811, which... we haven't even been able to find so we're not optimistic about even being able to get it, but it would work in a voltage follower configuration, letting us cut the DAC's output down to just 0V-1V. The problem here is I don't have a good LM4811 component model for the simulator so I'm not 100% sure of whether we need to alter the circuit's design further.

The question then, is: is there some way to get a better signal conditioning using the LM386 in our case, or any other widely available audio opamps we haven't considered? We don't need an amazing signal/noise ratio nor high specs at all since it's a project a bunch of first-timers should finish in a month, but we're not really experienced enough to tell exactly what we need here.

Thanks a lot in advance!

---

**EDIT**:

DAC electrical characteristics:

[image: DAC electrical characteristics]

---

**EDIT 2**:

We're using an [EDU-CIAA board (Spanish language link)](http://www.proyecto-ciaa.com.ar/devwiki/doku.php?id=desarrollo:edu-ciaa:edu-ciaa-nxp) which has an LPC4337 as its uC.

Comment: Why do you say that you can't feed the speaker directly from the DAC? 8-16 ohms is a much higher load than its minimum 1k ("high" loads are low resistance; high current). It might be _too_ high a load, though; check the datasheet.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it was bad wording. It needs a minimum of 1kOhm because I assume it can't handle higher currents. The uC as a whole has a recommended ~3mA for digital output pins so I assume it's related even though it's an analogue output.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the microcontroller?

Comment: Yes... a 1600 page manual. I'll post the DAC electric characteristics.

Comment: Your LM386 approach seems OK. Data sheet says that with a +5V DC supply, don't expect more than 3V peak-to-peak into 8-ohm load. A higher supply voltage would help avoid clipping waveform tops.

Comment: What worries us most is that we have a 0V-3.3V output that we're cutting down to +-0.06V to feed the opamp... Wouldn't this make us lose a lot of resolution and introduce noise to our audio signal?

Comment: DAC characteristics edited in!

Comment: Uh, I'm not sure how to link to this huge PDF that we got directly from the professors, but the uC itself seems to be an LPC4337, I'll edit that into the question too!

Comment: The LM386 voltage gain of 20 compensates for the "cut-down" D-to-A signal. No loss of resolution.  Any noise added by LM386 should be less than one least-significant bit.

Comment: The LM386 is **not** an opamp.  It is an audio power amplifier.  Connected as you have it, it has a fixed gain (amplification) of 20.  If you use it, the you'd do better to power it from more than 5V.  You will need to reduce your signal to 1/20 of your desired output voltage.

Comment: The LM4811 isn't an opamp, either.  It is a headphone driver.  A stereo headphone driver.

Comment: Attenuating the DAC output just as you have done doesn't affect its resolution, just makes each step smaller. Adds noise, sure, but not enough to notice with an LM386. Just go for it.

Comment: Can I connect a 9V battery directly to the lm386 then? We were planning on using the board's 5V out voltage

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I don't have enough reputation to upvote you all, but we did test the circuit as is and while we did have a lot of saturation noise it was eliminated for the frequencies we needed to handle by decoupling the power supply via a capacitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, testing the circuit with a protoboard checked out that it works perfectly, as long as the LM386's power supply is first decoupled with a bypass cap, otherwise we did have saturation noise at the output for frequencies above around 10kHz when we needed to handle up to at least 20kHz. The voltage divider didn't even need to attenuate the signal so much so a 10K resistor on top worked perfectly.

Sorry I don't have more details, we tested this two weeks ago and only now I remembered I had asked for help here.